# need to add onsubmit Event Attribute to a form via javascript and thank you

Tags: javascript, html, events, attributes, onsubmit

so here is what trying to get i need only a way to add ( onsubmit="submitted=true") to the form via javascript
and thank you guys

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var submitted=false;     
        
        </script>
        
    <iframe name="invisibleFrame" id="invisibleFrame" style="display:none;" onload="if(submitted)
            {window.location='Confirmation.html';}">
    </iframe>

<form action="https://link.com"  method="post"  target="invisibleFrame" onsubmit="submitted=true;" id="contact_form" autocomplete="on">
        <label for="entry.164" class="phone" >phone</label><br>
        <input type="text" name="entry.1647992981" placeholder="phone" required><br>
        <label for="entry.1">name</label><br>
        <input type="text" name="entry.1" placeholder="name" required><br>
        <label for="entry.7">city</label><br>
        <input type="text" name="entry.7" placeholder="city" required><br><br>
        <button type="submit" class="order-button">submit</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

actually im not good at all in coding so i just trying to get something done . thank you guys

Comment: See the [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) method.

Comment: What's the point of doing that? When the form is submitted, the page reloads, so any variable changes will be lost.

Comment: this is actually a google form

Comment: Now I see that it has a `target`, so the reload will happen in a different tab/window.

Comment: @barmar thanks for your comment and this is a google form and if you could help with that will appreciate it

Answer (score -1):

Use `addEventListener()` to add a listener that does what you want.

```
<script>
document.querySelector("form").addEventListener("submit", function() {
    submitted = true;
});
</script>
```

If you just want to make the iframe load the confirmation page when you submit the form, you can do that in the listener instead of setting the variable.

```
<script>
document.querySelector("form").addEventListener("submit", function() {
    let iframe = document.querySelector("#invisibleFrame");
    iframe.src = "Confirmation.html";
    iframe.style.display = 'block';
});
</script>
```

Comment: thank you so much @barmar i just tried this code but it seems that something is wrong cause the page didn't change to the confirmation page that i put in the iframe so something isnt't working properly, but anyway thanks for your fast replies and your willingness to help.

Comment: Why don't you just have the submit listener do `iframe.src = "Confirmation.html";`?

Comment: The `onload` in the iframe doesn't make sense. You're trying to access the parent window's `submitted` variable, but the iframe's `window.location`. It can only execute in one scope or the other.

Comment: okay please can you write it the code  as i mention im not good at all when it comes to coding but im trying to get things done my self  , so please if you can write the code and tell me where to add it and sorry for bothering , thanks again

Comment: If you're not good at coding, you need to find someone who is. You can't just expect random people on the Internet to write the code for you.

Comment: okay so basicaly the idea of this whole code is when some  one fill the form and click submited instead of showing the google form confirmation/submittion page i want to show them a new confirmation page  , it is actually working when im adding the ( onsubmit="submitted=true")  inside the form tag but as i mention i can't access to the form itselfe

Comment: thanks a lot again , in case you are wondering did the code that you write works , unfortunately no it didn't work  but your effort and your time are very much appreciated thanks again